# SDL 2 задать 4 координаты для картинки

Tags: c++, c, sdl

Возник вопрос по SDL2. нужно сделать так чтобы картинку я мог вставить по 4 координатам(для того чтобы растягивать изменять пропорциию картинки и тд) Возможно ли это? или как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Чем SDL_RenderCopy не подходит?

Comment: @Croessmah а как это сделать? ну вот к примеру мне нужно высота левой стороны 100 а правой 150?

Comment: То есть у картинки стороны могут быть не параллельны? Если да, тогда чистый SDL2 этого не умеет. Можно попробовать SDL2_gfx. Если там этого тоже нет, тогда либо рисовать попиксельно, либо переходить на opengl...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо) уже понял это) решил для этого считывать с картинки по одному пикселю и уже с пикселей делать нужные размеры картинки)

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал следующим образом: Создал класс `Sprite`, который хранит ссылку на `texture`, `draw_rect`, и написал в нем функцию `Draw`, которая рисует текстуру по координатам в `draw_rect`. Далее создается 4 объекта типа `Sprite` с разными координатами, и для каждой вызывается `Draw`.